# Couldn't use std::unordered_map in my code

Tags: c++, c++11, eclipse-cdt

I couldn't use std::unordered_map in my code, but it work fine with std::tr1::unordered_map. Is that a known issue? What should I do if I want to use std::unordered_map instead ?
OS: ubuntu
IDE: eclipse CDT
gcc: 4.7.2
compiler option: --std=c++11

This throw an error - Symbol 'unordered_map' could not be resolved:

```
    std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<test> > m;
```

Comment: Solutions differ based on what you need them to do, could you edit with a bit more information?

Comment: How were you trying to use it? What went wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ error: 'unordered\_map' does not name a type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733163/c-error-unordered-map-does-not-name-a-type)

Answer (score 2):

Missing symbols usually suggest that the wrong headers were included. Make sure to change the included header from

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
```

to

```
#include <unordered_map>
```

Comment: This is what i did before, but i will double check with it again tonight