# C++ error: 'unordered_map' does not name a type

Tags: c++, types, unordered-map

I am doing everything correctly as far as I can tell and I have gotten the error message:

```
error: 'unordered_map' does not name a type
error: 'mymap' does not name a type
```

In my code, I have:

```
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

//global variable
unordered_map<string,int> mymap;
mymap.reserve(7000);

void main {
  return;
}
```

I don't see what can be missing here....

EDIT: when I update my declaration to

```
std::tr1::unordered_map<string,int> mymap;
```

I an able to eliminate the first error, but when I try to reserve, I still get the second error message.

EDIT2: As pointed out below, reserve must go into main and I need to compile with flag

```
-std=c++0x
```

However, there still appear to be errors related to unordered_map, namely:

```
error: 'class std::tr1::unordered_map<std::basic_string<char>, int>' has no member named 'reserve'
```

Comment: provide a **complete** example

Comment: Which version of which compiler are you using? And with what options you're compiling your code? **Remember that `std::unordered_map` is available with C++11**.

Comment: g++.exe (g++ under MinGW). gcc version is 4.6.2. So is there a way for me to use unordered_map? When I use namespace tr1, I am able to declare my unordered_map but when I try to reserve space, I still get an error.

Comment: You cannot call a function or a method outside of a function or method definition. The call to `reserve` must be moved to `main`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Compile with `g++ -std=c++11` (my gcc version is `gcc 4.7.2`) AND

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//global variable
unordered_map<string,int> mymap;

int main() {
  mymap.reserve(7000); // <-- try putting it here
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For GCC 4.6.2 that should be `-std=c++0x`

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks. I forgot to mention my g++ version

Comment: Ah yes, stupid error, the reserve statement has to be inside main() and I do need to compile with the -std=c++0x flag for gcc 4.6.2. Unfortunately, I'm having some difficulties still with unordered_map, I am getting: error: 'class std::tr1::unordered_map<std::basic_string<char>, int>' has no member named 'reserve'

Comment: @user788171 See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/reserve. The ``reserve`` method is new in c++11. So either update your gcc or try other way around :)

Comment: The solution is to use the std=c++0x and remove the tr1/ in the include.

Answer (score 6):

> If you want to support `<unordered_map>` for versions older than c++11 use
>   `#include<tr1/unordered_map>` and declare your maps in the form :- `std::tr1::unordered_map<type1, type2> mymap`
>   which will use the technical report 1 extension for backward compatibility.

Comment: this should be the correct answer... not the chosen one.

Answer (score 3):

You can't `execute arbitrary expressions at global scope`, so you should put

```
mymap.reserve(7000);
```

inside main.

This is also true for other STL containers like map and vector.